# Can't understand the error message from blogdown

Tags: r, blogdown

I am trying to make a blog with `blogdown` using my windows machine, but get this error message when I use RStudio (File/New Project/New Directory/Website using blogdown/ ... and enter Directory name: "new"):

```
 setwd("C:/Users/AndrésLagerlöf/OneDrive - Andrés Lagerlöf Konsulttjänst AB/R/blog")
'C:\Users\Andr‚sLagerl”f\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" new site "new' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error in shell(cmd, mustWork = TRUE, intern = intern) : 
  '"C:\Users\AndrésLagerlöf\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" new site "new" --force -f toml' execution failed with error code 1
```

I do not know what to make out of this error message. Does anyone know how to fix this?

I use R version 4.0.0 and RStudio Version 1.2.5033.

Kind regards,
Andrés

Comment: Hej Andrés - looks like special characters in your file path (`ö` t.ex) are causing issues

Comment: Thank you @rg255 ! That seems reasonalbe. I tried again but this time set the R project directory directly under the root like this `C:\R_blogg` but I got the same error message.

'C:\Users\Andr‚sLagerl”f\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" new site "new_again' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error in shell(cmd, mustWork = TRUE, intern = intern) : 
  '"C:\Users\AndrésLagerlöf\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" new site "new_again" --force -f toml' execution failed with error code 1

Comment: The problem isn't with the blog location, it's with the location of the `hugo.exe` executable.  It looks like it should be located in a path with no special chars.  For whatever reason, R thinks the path to it is `C:\Users\Andr‚sLagerl”f\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" new site "new`:  something is messing up the quotes.

Comment: Thanks @user2554330! Strange anyhow? First: how comes that R thinks that the path to the new site is at `C:\Users\Andr‚sLagerl”f\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" new site "new`even though I created it under the root `C:\R_blogg`? Next: how do I move the `hugo.exe` to another directory (for example directly under `c` ?

Comment: First, it doesn't think that.  Second, try running `install_hugo()` and tell us where it got installed.

Comment: Thanks again @user2554330 :) . I used this command: `blogdown::install_hugo()` and it installed here:  `Hugo has been installed to C:\Users\AndrésLagerlöf\AppData\Roaming\Hugo`. How on earth do I change the location for the `hugo.exe` ?

Comment: See the very last paragraph in the help page `?install_hugo` for instructions to install it somewhere else.  Pick a directory without accented characters if you can! I don't think you can use `C:/` because of permission issues, but you can probably find something.  Then run `options(blogdown.hugo.dir = "C:/something/")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider installing Hugo to a path that does not contain multibyte characters. Per documentation `?blogdown::install_hugo`:

> If you want to install Hugo to a custom path, you can set the global option `blogdown.hugo.dir` to a directory to store the Hugo executable before you call `install_hugo()`, e.g., `options(blogdown.hugo.dir = '~/Downloads/hugo_0.20.1/')`.

This is also mentioned in [Appendix D.1](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/more-global-options.html) in the **blogdown** book. You'd better set this option in your `.Rprofile` (see [Section 1.4](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/global-options.html) for how), so the setting won't be lost after you restart R.

Comment: Many thanks @Yihui Xie ! I did that (i.e. used `options(blogdown.hugo.dir = "C:/R_blogg/hugo")` and then ``blogdown::install_hugo()` which seems to have worked fine :)  I got this message: